# Deserializing xml usind django REST when field names do not match

Tags: python, xml, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

How do you deserialize an xml file into a django model, when the xml field names do not match the model field names?

Here is an example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MaterialLot xmlns="http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401">
    <ID>B0000</ID>
    <StorageLocation>Box 1</StorageLocation>
</MaterialLot>
```

Here is the django model:

```
class MaterialLot(models.Model):
    material_lot_id = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LEN_ID, unique=True)
    storage_location = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LEN_LOC, blank=True)
```

And here is the serializer built using the django_rest framework:

```
class MaterialLotSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MaterialLot
        fields = ('material_lot_id', 'storage_location')
```

**The problem:**

I can not create a MaterialLot model field called 'ID' as ID is reserved for the model primary key. Hence, I need to map the XML 'ID' field to the 'material_lot_id' MaterialLot model field.

Ultimately, I want to read data from an XML file, and save the data in a django model:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    xmlstring = f.read()

stream = BytesIO(xmlstring)
data = XMLParser().parse(stream)
serializer = MaterialLotSerializer(data=data)        
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.save()
```

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I modified my model to make 'ID' the primary key. But this solution also appears to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework