# Changing the field name when using Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm feeding serialized data from the Django rest framework to a Javascript pivot table on my site. If I have a variable called 'created_on', the DRF uses that as the field name. What I want to display in my pivot table is the label which will be converted to 'Created On'.

As an example, my output from DRF is the following:

```
[{"created_on": "2016-04-23"}, {"created_on": "2016-05-23"}]
```

What I want is:

```
[{"Created on": "2016-04-23"}, {"Created on": "2016-05-23"}]
```

Is this possible without me overriding the serialization process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: That question is slightly different. The field name will still be in smaller letters and contain underscores if I follow that approach

Comment: no, it won't. You can define your alternate_name whatever you want. But if you want to, you can also override a Response object before returning it in a `perform_create`

Comment: If all cases look like this, couldn't you apply this transformation client side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No,** its not possible (currently) without overriding the serialization process.

**Why it is not possible?**

This is because the **alternate name which you want to use for `created_on` contains whitespace** and its not possible to define a field in your serializer having whitespaces in it. Also, there is no functionality currently to provide alternate name for a field to be used in serialization process.

**Possible Solution:**

You can override the `to_representation()` method of your serializer and there add a `Created On` key having value equal to the value of `created_on` key. Then all the serialized objects will contain a key `Created On`.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        primitive_repr = super(MySerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        primitive_repr['Created On'] = primitive_repr['created_on']
        return primitive_repr
```

**What if the alternate name did not contain any whitespaces?**

Had the alternate name did not contain any spaces between them, you could then have used `SerializerMethodField()` with `source` argument.

You could have done something like:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    alternate_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='created_on')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (.., 'alternate_name')
```

Comment: this gives me an error `ModelSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_alternate_name'`

Comment: @RajuSingh Can you post your serializer and the error traceback you are receiving, preferrably as another question.

Comment: I fixed it. the error was coming from some other reason.

Comment: @RajuSingh I have the same problem with ```ModelSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_```   could you tell me what was the problem?

Comment: @PaulFournel sorry I don't remember what was the actual problem with my code.but if you share what you are trying to do then I might be able to help.

Comment: @RajuSingh Thx, I created a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013211/how-to-deal-with-hyphen-and-django-rest-modelserializer

Answer (score 0):

In this method you need to use del method to delete dictionary items, because it will double the JSON output. So use this:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
       serializer = super().to_representation(instance)
       serializer['Link'] = serializer['url']
       serializer['Full Name'] = serializer['full_name']
       del (serializer['url'], serializer['full_name'])
       return serializer
```

Update, More elegant version:

```
 def to_representation(self, instance):   
        
        mapping={
            'old_field':'New Field',
             ...
        }
        
        serializer = super().to_representation(instance)
        for old, new in mapping.items():
            serializer[new] = serializer.pop(old, None)

        return serializer
```