# Using the reserved word "class" as field name in Django and Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, bioinformatics

## Description of the problem

Taxonomy is the science of defining and naming groups of biological organisms on the basis of shared characteristics. Organisms are grouped together into taxa (singular: taxon) and these groups are given a taxonomic rank. The principal ranks in modern use are domain, kingdom, phylum, class, order, family, genus and species.
More information on [Taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_(biology)) and [Taxonomic ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank) in Wikipedia.

Following the example for the **red fox** in the article **Taxonomic rank** in *Wikipedia* I need to create a JSON output like this:

```
{
    "species": "vulpes",
    "genus": "Vulpes",
    "family": "Canidae",
    "order": "Carnivora",
    "class": "Mammalia",
    "phylum": "Chordata",
    "kingdom": "Animalia",
    "domain": "Eukarya"
}
```

Since Django REST Framework creates the keys based on the field names, the problem arises with the taxonomic rank **class** (bold in the example) as it is a reserved word in Python and can't be used as a variable name.

## What I have tried

A model class created in Django would look like this:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    species = models.CharField()
    genus = models.CharField()
    family = models.CharField()
    # class = models.CharField() - class is reserved word in Python
    # class_ = models.CharField() - Django doesn't allow field names
    # ending with underscore. That wouldn't be either a satisfying solution.
    # further fields
```

## Question

Is there any possible way to solve this problem and generate the desired output?
If not, what is the best practice to work around this problem?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324691/rename-response-fields-django-rest-framework-serializer) for how to rename the field in django-rest-framework. You could use something like `species_class` or `klass` for your Django model field.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you very much, pal! With the help of the serializer method `to_representation` I have found a solution. The model field I call now `class_name`, which doesn't bother, as the client takes care only for the output. Would you add a couple of lines as answer, so I can upvote/accept it.

Comment: Glad that helped. It's probably better if you add your own answer, because you can show what you actually did to get it working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like below

```
class SpeciesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Species
        fields = (
            'url', 'id', 'canonical_name', 'slug',  'species', 'genus',
            'subfamily', 'family', 'order','class', 'phylum',
            'ncbi_id', 'ncbi_taxonomy',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('slug',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }

SpeciesSerializer._declared_fields["class"] = serializers.CharField(source="class_name")
```

As explained in below answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47717441/2830850

Answer (score 19):

You can rename field in the overloaded version of `get_fields()` method

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class_ = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    def get_fields(self):
        result = super().get_fields()
        # Rename `class_` to `class`
        class_ = result.pop('class_')
        result['class'] = class_
        return result
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this method too.

Comment: Definitely the cleanest method

Answer (score 16):

You can set the property of a class via strings as such:

```py
class SpeciesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    species = serializers.CharField()
    genus = serializers.CharField()
    family = serializers.CharField()
    vars()['class'] = serializers.CharField()
```

Comment: The simplest and the easiest method ever which is most suitable to the Python philosophy. Thank you for the tricks with the `vars()` function (or equivalent `locals()`).

Comment: This is such a beautiful and clean solution! It's crazy it took 4 years for this to be posted but I'm all here for it!

Comment: Note that there are concerns about modifying the results of `vars()` and `locals()` ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)) but this seems like a valid and safe modification to me. As long as your migration file gets correctly generated then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 5):

Other software developers in the field of Bioinformatics might be interested in a solution of this problem, so I post here my approach as suggested by **Alasdair**.

The goal is to create a model for a living species, for the sake of simplicity let's say an animal, and create an endpoint with Django REST Framework representing the correct taxonomic ranks.

**`models.py`**

```
from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    canonical_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    genus = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # we can't use class as field name
    class_name = models.CharField('Class', db_column='class', max_length=30)
    phylum = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # we don't need to define kingdom and domain
    # it's clear that it is an animal and eukaryote

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.canonical_name, self.species)
```

**`serializers.py`**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Species

class SpeciesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'canonical_name', 'species', 'genus',
            'subfamily', 'family', 'order', 'class_name', 'phylum')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # call the parent method and get an OrderedDict
        data = super(SpeciesSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        # generate a list of the keys and replace the key 'class_name'
        keys = list(data.keys())
        keys.insert(keys.index('class_name'), 'class')
        keys.remove('class_name')
        # remove 'class_name' and assign its value to a new key 'class'
        class_name = data.pop('class_name')
        data.update({'class': class_name})
        # create new OrderedDict with the order given by the keys
        response = OrderedDict((k, data[k]) for k in keys)
        return response
```

The method `to_representation` helps us to manipulate the output. I have put some extra work here to get the taxonomic ranks in the desired order.

Thus for the [red fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank#/media/File:Taxonomic_Rank_Graph.svg) the output looks like this:

**Red fox** (*Vulpes vulpes*)

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/animal/1",
    "id": 1,
    "canonical_name": "Red fox",
    "species": "Vulpes vulpes",
    "genus": "Vulpes",
    "family": "Canidae",
    "order": "Carnivora",
    "class": "Mammalia",
    "phylum": "Chordata"
}
```

It is a simplified example and in reality you'd have many more fields or possibly a model for every taxonomic rank, but somewhere you might come across the conflict between the reserved word `class` and the taxonomic rank [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(biology)).
I hope this can help other people too.