# How to user Django REST serializer do validation on reserved key?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

It might a simple question with eye blink workaround. But I can not be able to get it done.
I am now creating the `webhook` endpoint. And stuck at `serializer` class
My class can not use `from` as a class property

Python 3.6.4
Django==1.11.9
djangorest==3.7.7

```
@pytest.fixture
def like_object():
    """LIKE object response from Facebook"""
    return {
        "object": "page",
        "entry": [{
            "changes": [{
                "field": "feed",
                "value": {
                    "item": "reaction",
                    "verb": "add",
                    "reaction_type": "like",
                    "created_time": 1516183830,
                    "post_id": "1331351323541869_1844740022202994",
                    "from": {
                        "name": "Elcoie Sieve",
                        "id": "1639217166122728"
                    },
                    "parent_id": "1331351323541869_1844740022202994"
                }
            }],
            "time": 1516183830, "id": "1331351323541869"
        }]
    }
```

`serializers.py`

```
class FacebookReactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    value serializer the inner most of the payload
    """
    item = serializers.CharField()
    verb = serializers.CharField()
    reaction_type = serializers.CharField()
    created_time = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(4086831600)]
    )  # Limit the maximum epoch to 2099 July 4th 7:00AM
    post_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    from = FromSerializer()
    parent_id = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """
        `from` is a python reserved word the add _ to distinguish it from them
        :param attrs:
        :return:
        """
        from_ = attrs.get('from')
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

**Attempts:**

```
ffrom = FromSerializer(source='from')
```

Does not work

**Attempt2:**

```
class FacebookReactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    value serializer the inner most of the payload
    """
    item = serializers.CharField()
    verb = serializers.CharField()
    reaction_type = serializers.CharField()
    created_time = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(4086831600)]
    )  # Limit the maximum epoch to 2099 July 4th 7:00AM
    post_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    from_key = FromSerializer()
    parent_id = serializers.CharField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630356/using-the-reserved-word-class-as-field-name-in-django-and-django-rest-framewor
        :param instance:
        :return:
        """
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        keys = list(data.keys())
        keys.insert(keys.index('from_key'), 'from')
        keys.remove('from_key')
        from_key = data.pop('from_key')
        data.update({'from': from_key})
        response = OrderedDict((k, data[k]) for k in keys)
        return response

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

Testcase failed here is the breakpoint

```
(Pdb) serializer
FacebookReactionSerializer(data={'item': 'reaction', 'verb': 'add', 'reaction_type': 'like', 'created_time': 1516183830, 'post_id': '1331351323541869_1844740022202994', 'from': {'name': 'Krittuch Onnom', 'id': '1639217166122728'}, 'parent_id': '1331351323541869_1844740022202994'}):
    item = CharField()
    verb = CharField()
    reaction_type = CharField()
    created_time = IntegerField(validators=[<rest_framework.compat.MinValueValidator object>, <rest_framework.compat.MaxValueValidator object>])
    post_id = CharField(max_length=40)
    from_key = FromSerializer():
        name = CharField()
        id = CharField()
    parent_id = CharField()
(Pdb) serializer.errors
*** AssertionError: You must call `.is_valid()` before accessing `.errors`.
(Pdb) serializer.is_valid()
False
(Pdb) serializer.errors
{'from_key': ['This field is required.']}
```

**Attempt3:**
Also add the `._declared_fields['from_key']

```
class FacebookReactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    item = serializers.CharField()
    verb = serializers.CharField()
    reaction_type = serializers.CharField()
    created_time = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(4086831600)]
    )  # Limit the maximum epoch to 2099 July 4th 7:00AM
    post_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    from_key = FromSerializer()
    parent_id = serializers.CharField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        keys = list(data.keys())
        keys.insert(keys.index('from_key'), 'from')
        keys.remove('from_key')
        from_key = data.pop('from_key')
        data.update({'from': from_key})
        response = OrderedDict((k, data[k]) for k in keys)
        return response

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

FacebookReactionSerializer._declared_fields["from"] = serializers.CharField(source="from_key")
```

Debugging line:

```
(Pdb) serializer.is_valid()
False
(Pdb) serializer.errors
{'from_key': ['This field is required.'], 'from': ['Not a valid string.']}
```

I am getting close, but it is not enough

**Attempt4.1:**

Not work. Remain the same error. `from_key` still remain.
I wrote from `child` serializer. I must use `FromSerializer` not `CharField`.

```
    class FacebookReactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    value serializer the inner most of the payload
    """
    item = serializers.CharField()
    verb = serializers.CharField()
    reaction_type = serializers.CharField()
    created_time = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(4086831600)]
    )  # Limit the maximum epoch to 2099 July 4th 7:00AM
    post_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    from_key = FromSerializer()
    parent_id = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass


FacebookReactionSerializer._declared_fields["from"] = FromSerializer(source="from_key")
```

I can add `from` as a key now. But it does not remove the `from_key` out from the validation logic

```
(Pdb) serializer
FacebookReactionSerializer(data={'item': 'reaction', 'verb': 'add', 'reaction_type': 'like', 'created_time': 1516183830, 'post_id': '1331351323541869_1844740022202994', 'from': {'name': 'Krittuch Onnom', 'id': '1639217166122728'}, 'parent_id': '1331351323541869_1844740022202994'}):
    item = CharField()
    verb = CharField()
    reaction_type = CharField()
    created_time = IntegerField(validators=[<rest_framework.compat.MinValueValidator object>, <rest_framework.compat.MaxValueValidator object>])
    post_id = CharField(max_length=40)
    from_key = FromSerializer():
        name = CharField()
        id = CharField()
    parent_id = CharField()
    from = FromSerializer(source='from_key'):
        name = CharField()
        id = CharField()
(Pdb) serializer.is_valid()
False
(Pdb) serializer.errors
{'from_key': ['This field is required.']}
```

**Question:**
What is your workaround when `from`(reserved word) is a `key` and that key is a python class property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the reserved word "class" as field name in Django and Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630356/using-the-reserved-word-class-as-field-name-in-django-and-django-rest-framewor)

Comment: In my question it is about the reserved word `class`, but the principle should be same. Instead `from` use another field name in the model class and in the serializer manipulate the declared fields.

Comment: I had followed you given url and also tried your Dec2017 solution. My `from_key` is still remaining in the `errors`

Comment: It is different from the original question. Since I inherit from `Serializer` not `ModelSerializer`

Comment: Remove the `to_representation`. You need just the line with `_declared_fields`.

Comment: Thank you for fast response. Bad news. It is no different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@cezar Thank you very much!
The solution is so simple! I was confused at the early time. Because the given solutions are using `ModelSerializer` by that you have to put `fields` and coupling with model properties.

In my example is bare plain `Serializer` I don't need any of them.

From now on I would attacking this kind of problem by `Serializer` class

```
class FacebookReactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    value serializer the inner most of the payload
    """
    item = serializers.CharField()
    verb = serializers.CharField()
    reaction_type = serializers.CharField()
    created_time = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(4086831600)]
    )  # Limit the maximum epoch to 2099 July 4th 7:00AM
    post_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    parent_id = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass


FacebookReactionSerializer._declared_fields["from"] = FromSerializer()
```

Here is my debugging lines

```
(Pdb) serializer
FacebookReactionSerializer(data={'item': 'reaction', 'verb': 'add', 'reaction_type': 'like', 'created_time': 1516183830, 'post_id': '1331351323541869_1844740022202994', 'from': {'name': 'Krittuch Onnom', 'id': '1639217166122728'}, 'parent_id': '1331351323541869_1844740022202994'}):
    item = CharField()
    verb = CharField()
    reaction_type = CharField()
    created_time = IntegerField(validators=[<rest_framework.compat.MinValueValidator object>, <rest_framework.compat.MaxValueValidator object>])
    post_id = CharField(max_length=40)
    parent_id = CharField()
    from = FromSerializer():
        name = CharField()
        id = CharField()
(Pdb) serializer.is_valid()
True
```

Comment: Thanks, why is it so hard to find it in documentation? :/