# Changing the default SQL column name transition rules in Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I am using MySQL and Django in my backend, and the big issue now is that I use underscores in MySQL, while I have to use camelCase in Django ORM.So the question is, can I somehow tell Django to insert underscores in those places where it encounters uppercase letter in the middle of the word, so that

`ownerAccount = models.ForeignKey(ownerAccount, models.CASCADE)`

becomes `owner_account_id` in MySQL.

I know there is [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column) solution, but it sounds like a hell to me and violation of DRY. I feel like there just should be a clean and quick solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) in PEP8, variable names should be written in lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Therefore your approach:

```
ownerAccount = models.ForeignKey(ownerAccount, models.CASCADE)
```

is wrong. And it is more than one issue:

1) the property name should be written as `owner_account`;

2) the class name should be written as `OwnerAccount`, thus `models.ForeignKey(OwnerAccount)`, even better is to enclose the class name in quotes, like `models.ForeignKey('OwnerAccount')`, to make it more flexible;

3) for better readability and conforming to Django conventions you should use the keyword argument `on_delete` like `on_delete=models.CASCADE`.

The `db_column` has it's justification and without it the framework would be extremely unflexible and completely unusable in many cases.

To summarize, the quick and proper solution is to use `snake_case` for the property names of the model class (or any class).

EDIT:
If you create a REST API with Django REST Framework and want to have different names for the keys, like for example:

```
{'ownerAccount': 'some value'}
```

instead of:

```
{'owner_account': 'some_value'}
```

then you can change the output of the field names. There are two answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630356/using-the-reserved-word-class-as-field-name-in-django-and-django-rest-framewor) which can help you further.

Once again I'd like to stress, regardless of the REST API, you should still conform to the PEP8 conventions and use `snake_case` for any class properties and methods.

Comment: And what if I have to use camelCase in my REST app ?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan Do you use Django REST Framework for your REST API?