# Nested Django REST

Tags: python, django, rest

It seems very simple to do nested serializer in Django REST. 
But I can not find anything wrong in my code.carts does not shown up
I had followed http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships
Only one thing different is I use `JSONField`. 
It should not be a problem.

```
class MailAPIOrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    variant = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('category', 'product', 'variant')

    def get_variant(self, obj: OrderItem):
        return obj.product.get('level_two')

    def get_category(self, obj: OrderItem):
        return obj.product.get('service_name')

    def get_product(self, obj: OrderItem):
        return obj.product.get('product_name')

class MailAPIOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    carts = MailAPIOrderItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            ...
            'carts'
        )

    def get_staff_name(self, order: Order):
        return order.staff.full_name

class OrderItem(AbstractSoftModelController):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_items', verbose_name=_('Order'))
    product = JSONField(verbose_name=_('Product'))
```

**My Temporal Solution:**
Right now. I am working around by replacing 
`carts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`
And in the method I use

```
def get_carts(self, order: Order):
    qs = order.order_items.all()
    serializer = MailAPIOrderItemSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model `Order` you have backref field `order_items` not `carts`. So try change field name in `MailAPIOrderSerializer`:

```
order_items = MailAPIOrderItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = (
        ...
        'order_items'
    )
```

Comment: OK. It works. However, I wants `carts` not `order_items`. How can I alias `order_items` to `carts`?

Comment: @Sarit try to specify `source` argument: `carts= MailAPIOrderItemSerializer(source='order_items', many=True, read_only=True)`. See details here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: Yes. I am about to try `source` after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework. Thank you very much.