# Django Rest Framework serializer `source` giving weird required error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API that sends me fields with field names that don't match the ones in my model (and that I have no control over) and am trying to map them in the serializer, but for some reason when I actually implement this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='customer_email')
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='first name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='last name')
    address = serializers.CharField(source='customer_address')
    phone = serializers.CharField(source='customer_phone')
    messenger_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='messenger user id')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'phone', 'messenger_id',)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "phone": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "first_name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "last_name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "messenger_id": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "address": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

However, among those fields, the only one that's actually required in my model is the `email` field. I used the `source=` parameter according to the top rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework), but am not sure what's causing the issue here.

Thanks!

Comment: I can see you missed underscore (`_`) in your source of `first name`, `last name`, `messenger user id`  it should be `first_name`, `last_name` and `messenger_user_id`, also post your view as well.

Comment: why are you explicitly defining the serializer fields, do you want your API to expose different field names than model fields.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem with my serializer, until I realized that

- the "fields"-attribute in class Meta represents the fields of the API and not the fields of the actual model.
- the "source"-parameter represents the fields of the model.

So if this is approximately what your model looks like:

```
class User(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    messenger_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Then maybe this could work:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    customer_email = serializers.EmailField(source='email')
    customer_address = serializers.CharField(source='address')
    customer_phone = serializers.CharField(source='phone')
    messenger_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='messenger_id')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'customer_email', 'customer_address', 'customer_phone', 'messenger_user_id',)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Documentation:

> **required** - Normally an error will be raised if a field is not supplied
>   during deserialization. Set to false if this field is not required to
>   be present during deserialization.
>
> Setting this to False also allows the object attribute or dictionary
>   key to be omitted from output when serializing the instance. If the
>   key is not present it will simply not be included in the output
>   representation.
>
> Defaults to True.

In short, by defining the serializer fields "by hand" and not using the automatic creation, you run over the pulled "required" field - and make it default back to true. change your code like so:

```
email = serializers.EmailField(source='customer_email')
first_name = serializers.CharField(source='first name',required = False)
last_name = serializers.CharField(source='last name',required = False)
address = serializers.CharField(source='customer_address',required = False)
phone = serializers.CharField(source='customer_phone',required = False)
messenger_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='messenger user id',required = False)
```

Also, it seems you missed the underscores in some places. + I will recommend you to just use fields = ('**all**') or if you want to exclude some fields -> exclude = (''#enter excluded names here). so to coclude:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='customer_email',required = False)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='first_name',required = False)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='last_name',required = False)
    address = serializers.CharField(source='customer_address',required = False)
    phone = serializers.CharField(source='customer_phone',required = False)
    messenger_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='messenger_user_id',required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = () # insert excluded files here
```

To finish up, I recommened you checking if you really want to explicitly state all fields when creating the serializer class. Most cases you can avoid that and let the Django-rest-framework magic work it out for you.

Comment: But what if these fields _are_ required? Is there a way to make `required=True` working, with respect to `source` keys?

Answer (score 2):

An addition to the answer of idik if you mend to combine fields from different models.
According to the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) you should use the dotted notation here:

> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. May be a method that only takes a self argument, such as URLField(source='get_absolute_url'), or may use dotted notation to traverse attributes, such as EmailField(source='user.email').

When you have a User model with an first_name, last_name etc and a linked Customer model, it should be something along the following lines:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='customer.email')
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    address = serializers.CharField(source='customer.address')
    phone = serializers.CharField(source='customer.phone')
    messenger_id = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Where is this `customer` coming from? Is this an attribute on the `User` model and can be accessed, is that what you meant?