# Renaming DRF serializer fields

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF serializers to validate incoming data that I retrieve from a JSON API. I'm trying to rename some awkwardly named fields from the response, making it easier to use the `serializer.data` further on in my code.

Data received from the API looks like this:

`{"FunnyNamedField": true, "AnotherWeirdField": false}`

And handling code:

```
resp = requests.get([...])
resp.raise_for_status()
ser = MyFunnyDataSerializer(data=resp.json())
if ser.is_valid():
    do_domething_with(ser.data)
```

I would like the serializer to translate the incoming field names to something more consise. `ser.data` could look like: `{'funny': True, 'weird': False}`.

What I tried but doesn't work as I hoped:

```
class MyFunnyDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    funny = serializers.Booleanfield(source='FunnyNamedField')
```

Is there any way to achieve this without reverting to a `SerializerMethodField`?

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: This link proposes to use source=, which only works for ModelSerializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override BaseSerializer to achieve this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CustomSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {
            <datas>
        }
```

You can do some specific modifications on instance serialization with custom methods.

Another solution could be to write your own validator for one field: [Field Validator Method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation).

So in this documentation example you could modify value before return it.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_title(self, value):
        """
        Check that the blog post is about Django.
        """
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
        if value == "something":
            value = "something_else"
        return value
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I edited your answer slightly, the second solution only allowed to alter the data in the serializer, not the field names, so I removed t (did not apply to the question).