# How to use custom name instead of related_name in serializer in case of reverse relation?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

In case of reverse relation between two models we can fetch all related child rows in our parent serializer via the related_name argument of ForeginKeyField. I want to use a different name instead of the related_name
to fetch those row.

Below is the example that is conventionally used.

**Models**

```
class Library(models.Model):
    libraryId = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    libraryName = models.CharField(max_length=150)



class Book(models.Model):
    bookId = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    fk_book_libraryId = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='library_book_relation', on_delete=models.CASCADE )
```

**Serializers**

```
class BookSerializer(models.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'


class LibrarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lib_name = serializers.CharField(source='libraryName')
    library_book_relation = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    '''
    I don't want to use the name 'library_book_relation'. I want to make   it as short custom name like the 'lib_name'.
    '''

    class Meta:
        model = Library
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['library_book_relation']
```

I want some thing like below:

```
class Meta:
        model = Library
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['all_books']
```

Please don't make it as duplicate someone. Although some similar questions exist but my problem was not solved yet, that's why this question arisen here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is not duplicated? Looks **exactly** like what's said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22958798/1060162).

In summary, you can use a `SerializerMethodField` to give it a custom name and then return what you want inside of it (just remember it is read-only) or, depending on which property you want from the `ForeignKey` model, you can use the `source` attribute in a regular field (`CharField`, for instance).

#### Update:

Doesn't something like this work for you?

```py
short_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

[...]

def get_short_name(self, obj):
    return obj.library_book_relation
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Perhaps you couldn't catch my focus. Please read the question again. I didn't ask about renaming the usual model field. I mentioned the 'reverse relationship'.

Which link you referred, I already implemented it in my code. See the 'lib_name' field.

Conventionally, In case of getting all child rows related to the primary key of the parent model we normally used the 'related_name' argument. I want to change that 'related_name' as per my need.

Comment: @MuhammadSH Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve (i.e. why do you want to give a shorter name to this field in the serializer instead of changing its name in the model and why it's important to make it shorter)? There's no way to do this without actually referencing the original related name in some place. I've updated my answer to use `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: According to your update `SerializerMethodField` gives the following error-  "Object of type 'RelatedManager' is not JSON serializable"

Comment: The project I am working with now is a big e commerce like platform. Too many tables there are and a chain of relations to each other. To make easily recognizable to other programmers I should maintain some naming convention in the model (that's why the name can be longer there). When I serialize those model field (to make an api for 3rd party) I shouldn't send them the long name which I used in my database. It is a security issue also but I don't know why you suggested me to change the 'related_name' in model !