# Alter the parameter name during serialization

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am having struggles with the alteration on the parameter name during serialization with DRF.

My input would be a JSON with some parameters:

```
{
"limit": 10,
"type": "group",
[...]
}
```

and my serializer looks like:

```
class RankSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    limit = serializers.IntegerField(default=100, min_value=1)
    type = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_type(self, t):
        # validation
```

But this doesn't sound right. *Type* is a reserved keyword in Python so I don't want to use it as a parameter name. I'd like to somehow map it to i.e *result_type* or something like this.
I already tried using the *source=* parameters as follows:

```
result_type = serializers.CharField(source='type')
```

but this doesn't seem to work on non-model inputs.

I cannot rename the parameter on the frontend level.

I'd appreciate any tips regarding this issue. Cheers.

Comment: Same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: This question is not about Django Models.

Answer (score 1):

I searched https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/ of DRF docs but was unable to find a viable solution. So I subclassed the Serializer class provided by DRF and created a CustomSerializer. In that, I subclassed the run_validation method. In that, before calling super().run_validation(), I access the initial_data passed and change it to the desired mapping as you mentioned. This information of field mappings I store in the Meta class nested inside RankSerializer. So for example, you have fields F1, F2, F3(in JSON data, for example) whose values you want to populate in fields named M1, M2, M3, you just have to write in the Meta class in the field_mappings dictionary the following :

```
field_mappings = {
'M1': 'F1', 
'M2':'F2', 
'M3': 'F3'
}
```

The other fields will function normally.
Here is the code

```
import rest_framework.serializers as serializers
from .models import Rank
from rest_framework.fields import empty

class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def run_validation(self, data=empty):
        for (field, mapping) in self.Meta.field_mappings.items():
            data[field] = data[mapping]
            del data[mapping]
        return super().run_validation(data=data)

class RankSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    limit = serializers.IntegerField(default=100, min_value=1)
    result_type = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        field_mappings = {
            'result_type': 'type'
        }
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)



'''
Please run the code below in the InteractiveShell to verify the result

from myapp.serializers import RankSerializer
serializer = RankSerializer(data={"limit":15, "type":"Hello"})
serializer.is_valid()
'''
```

After running the code in the multi line comments to verify the result here is the snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found was to modify the parameter name in the validate method as follows:

```
def validate(self, data):
    data = super(RankSerializer, self).validate(data)
    data['result_type'] = self.validate_result_type(self.initial_data.get('type'))
    return data
```

Not sure if this is the cleanest way to do it, but I prefer it over @punter147 answer.