# Rename field in Serializer.data

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am currently implementing an API client for which I want to validate the request sent using serializers.
To do so, I create my serializer like this:

```
class TransactionRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    counterparty = serializers.UUIDField(required=False)
    from_datetime = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, source='from')
    to_datetime = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, source='to')
    transaction_type = serializers.CharField(required=False, source='type')
```

Issue is that source doesn't fit my usage, because when I do serializer.data, I get:

```
{'from_datetime': '2020-07-07T16:08:00.313236+02:00'}
```

Instead of

```
{'from': '2020-07-07T16:08:00.313236+02:00'}
```

Those data are then passed as params for my request, like requests.get('', params=params)

Of course, I cannot name the field "from" as it is reserved. Any idea about how can I get "from" in my serializer.data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change field name in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework)

Comment: No because it is changing the source, and I try to change the target but the name matches a reserved language name.

Answer (score 0):

I tink this has already been answered.

Please take a look at this question: [How to change field name in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework)

I think the same solution will work for you.

Comment: I try to do the opposite as mentionned in this answer, as I understand it. My field should be named at the end "from" in the .data. The source attribute will do the opposite: read the "from" from dict and put the field_name in .data, but as you can see, field_name cannot be "from". Or maybe I missing something in the answer?

Comment: The second example (alternate_name) is exactly what you need, I think.

Comment: In the example, alternate_name will be changed to location right? When running the solution, when at the end I call serializer.data, I retrieve {'locations': OrderedDict([('test', 'A')])}. I want to do exactly the opposite: I want to get {'alternate_name': ...} for the example, or in my case: {'to': '...'}

Comment: To be clearer, in the example, field_name = xxxxx(*args, **kwargs) and in serializer.data, field_name appears. What I try to do is old_name = xxxx(*args, **kwargs) and in serializer.data, "to" appears instead. It's a reverse usage of Serializer. I used a lot source='' or SerializerMethodField, but those are for the opposit way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, so I switched to Serializer.validated_data instead so I can use source.

Answer (score 0):

this example as same the question :
model:

```
from django.db import models
class ReceiveCallbackUrl(models.Model):
    From = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    to = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    messageid = models.IntegerField()
```

serializer:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer,SerializerMethodField
from .models import ReceiveCallbackUrl


class ReceiveCallbackUrlModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    From = SerializerMethodField('from')

    class Meta:
        model = ReceiveCallbackUrl
        fields = ['From', 'to', 'message', 'messageid']
```

view:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializer import ReceiveCallbackUrlModelSerializer
class ReceiveCallbackUrlAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ReceiveCallbackUrlModelSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(request.POST, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```