# Django Rest Framework: source / re-name without re-confirming the field settings

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'd like to change many fields name in DRF `ModelSerializer` without the need to re-typing the fields.

According a post on SO ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework)), one can re-name a field name within the serializer by using `source`, such as:

```
newName = serializers.CharField(source='old_name')
```

However, this method takes away the benefits of using a `ModelSerializer` as you essentially do the work twice. This become heavy when you have many fields adhering to one internal naming convention but want to display another naming convention within the API.

in my case, I have a model field such as:

```
product_uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

In the API, I'd like the field to be called `'uid'`.

If I would do the following:

```
uid = serializers.UUIDField(source=product_uid)
```

would result in `editable=True`

Is there a way to reference to a `ModelField` and keep its definition intact according the Model (as you normally do when using `serializers.ModelSerializer`) but only change the name, e.g. something like: `uid = serializers.ModelField(source=product_uid)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your field not to be editable, you can use the `read_only` parameter (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)

You can try:

```
uid = serializers.UUIDField(source=product_uid, read_only=True)
```

You can also use the ModelSerializer using [extra_kwargs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) :

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['product_uid', 'field_a', 'field_b']
        extra_kwargs = {'product_uid': {'source': 'uid'}}  # Add `'read_only': True` if needed
```

If you have many fields, you can generate `extra_kwargs` programmatically

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to inherit already made work that has been made in models.py, To illustrate assume you have 70 DecimalFields with individual settings of default, min max, lengths etc. but you want to assign a new external name on those fields within the api. It looks a bit unwise to repeat the same work again within serializers when you only want to change the name,

Comment: You mean, you have 70 fields which you want to rename the name between Serializer and Model ? Or do you have 70 fields and want to change the name of only one field ?

Comment: You could use the [extra_kwargs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) `source` if you want, but you still have to specify the source for all your fields

Comment: '70 fields which you want to rename the name between Serializer and Model" (I have an inhouse standard: name_regnummer_field its not pretty when you want to expose it, I rather want to show name only)

Comment: I edited my answer, please check if it's fine for you

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and help, let me look into it/try it and come back